# Initialize all disks on Windows but only assign drive letters G through Z with PowerShell

Tags: windows, azure, powershell

We use a template to provision a VM in Azure with multiple new disks. We need to run a PowerShell script to automatically format and assign drive letters to these disks, such as below ([source](http://naeem.khedarun.co.uk/blog/2015/12/03/attaching-and-formatting-drives-with-azure-arm-and-powershell/)). However, the number of drives could be anywhere from 1 to 20 and we want to limit the letters to G through Z. Is there a way to tell PowerShell to only use drive letters in this range?

```
Get-Disk | ` 
Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' | ` 
Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | ` 
New-Partition -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | ` 
Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "datadisk" -Confirm:$false
```

**Update:**
The accepted answer below led me to this final solution:

```
$CurrentDiskLetter = [byte][char]'Z'  # As we decrement this value, it will change to Y, X, W, etc.
$Disks = Get-Disk | Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' 
Foreach  ($D in $Disks) {
    $D | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | 
    New-Partition -DriveLetter ([char]$CurrentDiskLetter) -UseMaximumSize | 
    Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "datadisk" -Confirm:$false
    $CurrentDiskLetter--  
}
```

Comment: By the way, backticks are not needed there at all. You can break a line after a Pipe `|` symbol. This behavior is natively supported and encouraged when it makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed possible.

You can achieve that fairly easily by declaring an array containing the byte representation of the desired letters.

Using `[byte][char]'g'` and `[byte][char]'z'`, you can get the values **103** and **122** From there, you initialize an array in Powershell for that range.

`$DiskArray = 103..122 # G to Z`

Note that you wwant to use either both upper case or lower case to ensure the range you get is good. 
From there, you can convert the integers back to a char by casting them.

See the modified script below.

```
$DiskArray = 103..122 # G to Z 
$DiskArrayIndex = 0

$Disks = Get-Disk |  Where partitionstyle -eq 'raw' 

Foreach  ($D in $Disks) {
        $D | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR -PassThru | 
        New-Partition -DriveLetter ([Char]$DiskArray[$DiskArrayIndex]) -AssignDriveLetter -UseMaximumSize | 
        Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "datadisk" -Confirm:$false

        $DiskArrayIndex+=1
}
```

**Additional note**

You do not need the backtick at all in your code to cut line.
Lines in Powershell naturally can be broken after a pipe symbol `|` is inserted.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my question to include my final solution, inspired by your answer.